# get form values other than by name in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, php, codeigniter-form-helper

hi i am using codeigniter . i have a form , there i add hidden fields dynamically . so every hidden field is `<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value="+$(this).attr('title')+">`  so the name is equal .

the problem is when i submit the form and try to get my hiden field values i can only get one hidden field value , because the names are same

i print my form values

```
print_r($this->input->post());
```

i have 2 hidden fields but i get only one

```
Array
(
    [hidden] => march
    [textbox] => march
    [mysubmit] => Submit
)
```

i can change the name dynamically of hidden field when creating , but then i don't know exactly the name of my hidden field ,

how can i get hidden field values with same name ?? is there any way to get form values other than by name ?? i tried and can not find an answer , please help .............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use brackets in your `name` attributes:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[]'>
<!--                            ^^^^                                   -->
```

This will allow PHP to accept multiple inputs with the same name as an array of values, so in this case, `$_POST['hidden']` will return an array of strings.

By default they are indexed starting at 0, so `$_POST['hidden'][0]` will get you the first one, `$_POST['hidden'][1]` will get you the second, etc., however - you can explicitly index them if it's easier for you, either with numbers or strings.

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[first]'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[second]'>
```

Or:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[0]'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden[1]'>
```

You can nest these as deep as you want like `hidden[first][1][]`, and they will be treated similarly to a PHP array when you get the `$_POST` values, but you need the brackets in the HTML.

Without brackets, only the last field's value will be available in the `$_POST` array. This is a PHP feature, Codeigniter can't do anything about it.